# Using a scanner in a non-static string?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a code that searches for words in a text file, but the scanner that runs it is located in the public static void main(String[] args) for the class.  I need to be able to move the scanner into a string, so that rather than inputting the word that I want to search for in the code manually as a word in quotes, I can find it by referencing the string in another class's main method, with a constructor that takes in words.  However, when I try to move the scanner out of main and into a new public string, I have to change System.out.println(arr[0]) to return arr[0], and the program won't run unless I change the string type to static.  When I do that, nothing comes out in the console, as opposed to the correct output being displayed when run in main.
Here is my code:
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Database {
    public String arr45;
    public String hi(String firstName, String lastName){
Scanner theScanner = null;




    try{    
     theScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("Cast.txt"));}

    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    while( theScanner.hasNext()){
    String movie = theScanner.nextLine();
    String[] arr = movie.split("/");

    if(movie.contains(lastName + ", " + firstName))
    {

        theScanner.close();
        String arr45 = arr[0];  


    }

    }
    return arr45;
    }
    public static void main( String[] args ){


}
    }
```

This code works when everything inside string is in main, and

```
if(movie.contains(lastName + ", " + firstName))
```

has the actual name that I'm searching for in quotes in the parentheses and if return is replaced with

```
System.out.println.
```

I've tried a lot of things but I can't seem to figure out how to turn the original code into a string that takes in two variables and does the same thing.
Below is the original code that worked correctly:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Database {
    public static String arr2 = "";

    public static void main( String[] args ){
    Scanner theScanner = null;




    try{    
     theScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("Cast.txt"));}

    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    while( theScanner.hasNext()){
    String movie = theScanner.nextLine();
    String[] arr = movie.split("/");

    if(movie.contains("Hanks, Tom"))
    {

    System.out.println(arr[0]); 
    }
    }

    theScanner.close();
    }

}
```

Last thing- for sure.  Probably.  I was required to make a method that would search for all the actors with a certain word in their name and I got it to work, but it only runs for one line of text.  Please tell me how I can get this to go to the next line and do it again when the line is finished:

```
        while( theScanner6.hasNextLine()){
        String movie = theScanner6.nextLine();
        String[] arr = movie.split("/");

            for(int i = 1; i< 400; i++){

                    if(arr[i].contains(wordD)){
                        int placeholder = i;
                        String[] firstW = arr[placeholder].split(","); 
                         movie = theScanner6.nextLine();

                        System.out.println(firstW[1] + " " + firstW[0]);
                        arr45 = arr[placeholder];   

                    }

            }


        }
        while( !theScanner6.hasNextLine()){
            theScanner6.close();
        }

        return arr45;
        }
```

Comment: Sensible indentation would make your code a lot less mad looking.

Comment: I usually do all of my indentation corrections once I know my code works and is complete.

Comment: That means you are going to fix your indentation after the point you are showing people your code and asking for their help. That is too late.

Comment: Well I'm not asking for help on making it look better, just on making it work better.

Comment: You're asking people to read your code to help you, and you are making it unnecessarily difficult by not offering it in a readable way.

Comment: What's the point of doing indentation corrections AFTER the code is complete? The whole point of indenting is to make everything easier DURING coding. After you're done coding, the style doesn't matter at all. In fact, some companies intentionally make everything garbage looking and change all the variable names to not make sense in order to throw off anyone who tries to steal code (this is called obfuscating the code, btw). But all that is done AFTER the code is finished; while they're developing the code, it should always be styled properly, and that includes indentation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question first instantiate your `Database` then call the method,

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    Database db = new Database();
    db.hi("first", "last");
}
```

Also,

```
String arr45 = arr[0];
```

should be

```
arr45 = arr[0];
```

or you shadow the field defined earlier (and then the shadow goes out of scope).

Comment: I did that in the other class where I want to call it but I got an error that said
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at Database.<init>(Database.java:7)

Comment: I fixed it- I had placed the code in the class that it was referencing.  One (probably) last thing.  When it prints out the list, due to the format of the original file, anything that would have started with the word "The" is formatted like "movie title, The".  How would I be able to move "The" to the front?